# Network management problem in genymotion and creating problem while opening oracle vm virtualbox

Tags: kotlin, mobile, developer-tools

I have recently started app development course while learning in android studio it was going smoothly but after it make me download Genymotion it give network management problem to unable to connect with the ethernet connection and its not connect connecting with android studio and after genymotion activation it takes alot of time to open and virtualbox ask user access control over and over.

i tried to change the network management and after laptop shutdown it automatically change it network and its is not opening fast takes time and also not opening with android studio while using android studio
please help me its is not working at all.